# Regex: Get first value from single line

Tags: regex, xml

I have the below xml on a single line, I want to get the string of DBB and replace it using regex

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[DBA DB].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.\test;Initial Catalog=DBA;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=B;</ConfiguredValue></Configuration><Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[DBB DB].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.\test;Initial Catalog=DBB;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=C;</ConfiguredValue></Configuration></DTSConfiguration>
```

I have the following which works on multi line xml but not this single line example

```
Data Source=.+?(?=[a-z])*\;Initial Catalog=DBB;(.*?)Integrated(.*?)[^;]*;
```

The above regex highlights both DBA and DBB and ends there.

Could you help in finding the missing piece in the regex I have created

Comment: Why are you using a regex? Does your language not have proper XML support?

Comment: It looks like part of a .net config file... there are tools out there to parse and process it... use them.

Comment: Just an fyi, don't use regex for xml parsing.

Comment: My aim was to do a simple string replace then get involved in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Data Source=.+?` with `Data Source=[^<]+?` to avoid traversing the start of the tag.

Comment: It's far from perfect, you should really use an XML parser if possible, for the sanity of the developers that might touch your code later.